# Find all instances where has_many association array size equals a set number

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'd like to be able to do something like this. Where `boat.classifications` would normally return an array of associated classifications.

`Boat.where(classifications.size == 3)`

I can do this, but I'd like to be able to call `.pluck` on it and the below code won't allow for that.

```
Boat.all.select do |boat|
    boat.classifications.length == 3
end
```

Comment: What do you exactly want to achieve? To get `Boat` where `classifications` length less or grater then some value?

Comment: I'd like to find all the boats where the length of the classifications array is 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `GROUP` + `HAVING`:

```
count = 3
Boat
  .joins(:classifications)
  .group(:id)
  .having('count(boats.id) = ?', count)
```

And you can chain it with `pluck` or whatever you need.